# Can not install the CRAN package `caret` on IBM Watson Studio R notebooks

Tags: r, data-science-experience, rnotebook, watson-studio

While trying to install the R package `caret` on IBM Watson Studio R notebooks, it installs a lot of dependencies but in the end fails with non-zero exit status errors. The dependency `recipes` cannot be installed for some reason.

```
install.packages('caret')

Installing package into ‘/.../R/libs’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘numDeriv’, ‘SQUAREM’, ‘lava’, ‘kernlab’, ‘CVST’, ‘DEoptimR’, ‘prodlim’, ‘DRR’, ‘robustbase’, ‘sfsmisc’, ‘ipred’, ‘dimRed’, ‘lubridate’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘gower’, ‘RcppRoll’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘recipes’, ‘withr’

Warning message in install.packages("caret"):
“installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("caret"):
“installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `caret` imports a lot of other R packages. One of them is `recipes`, which in-turn import packages like `purrr`, `lubridate`, `tibble` etc. Newest `recipes` packages seems to be relying on a mapping function called `map_dfr` from the `purrr` package which is not loaded to the namespace. Updating `purrr` (and maybe a list of other package) might solve the issue. I chose to go one version down on `recipes` and save a lot of re-installations. This worked for me:

```
install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/recipes/recipes_0.1.0.tar.gz')
install.packages('caret')
library('caret')
```

Comment: Yes, since the version of RStudio on DSX is not the current version, you usually have to go down one version on the libraries to get them if you get the non-zero issue.

Comment: Good to know. This question was specifically about the Jupyter R Notebooks on DSX.